# Magento: Moving Files and Database from windows to linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, windows, magento, ubuntu

I have stuck in a problem and have been trying to resolve it for last five days but could not get success up till now. Please help me out...

I have moved all the files and database one of my magento's project from my PC (running windows 7) to laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
- I installed xampp and import the database (Successfully imported)
- Made a virtual host (running fine)
- But as soon as moved my project files in vitualhost folder, it continuously redirecting to http://mylocalhost.local/downloader and throwing "Access Forbidden ERROR 403".

System.log of my magento's project is full of such type of errors

Warning:implexml_load_string():in E:\virtualhosts\myproject\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 444

Please help me out...

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess files? Also, have you set your (un)secure urls in the Magento configuration?

Answer (score 0):

please check the files under www/yourDomain.com/public: 
 1. permissions of files. should be : 0755
 2. group of files : www-data

and then restart apache:

> sudo service apache2 restart